# Pass result .js to another .js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass result from var url (index.js) to game.js, so that it follows the process that I need. Is that possible? Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much.
I put the complete index.js code so that you understand what you want to achieve.
I've tried to do it in many ways, but none successfully, I don't know what else to try.

*index.js*

```
      //SELECT CATEGORY
//CATEGORY => 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 32

const obj = {
    url: 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20',
    category: '',
    difficulty: ''
}

let newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');

function selectCat() {
    var c = document.getElementById('cat').value;
    console.log(c);
    obj.category = c;
    newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');
}

//SELECT DIFFICULTY
//DIFFICULTY => any, easy, medium, hard
function selectDiff() {
    var d = document.getElementById('diff').value;
    console.log(d);
    obj.difficulty = d;
    newUrl = Object.values(obj).join('');
}


  /*NEST VALUE TO CATEGORY AND DIFFICULTY
    NEXT TO THE URL TO GET THE NEWURL*/

  //CLICK EVENT BUTTON


  var btnFetch = document.getElementById('fetch');

  /*var url =*/ btnFetch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(newUrl);});
```

*game.js*

```
fetch(
    url
    )
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(loadedQuestions => {
      console.log(loadedQuestions.results);
      questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
        const formattedQuestion = {
          question: loadedQuestion.question
        };

        const answerChoices = [...loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers];
        formattedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        answerChoices.splice(
        formattedQuestion.answer - 1,
        0,
        loadedQuestion.correct_answer
        );
        answerChoices.forEach((choice, index) => {
          formattedQuestion["choice" + (index + 1)] = choice;
        });

        return formattedQuestion;
      });

      startGame();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: To export a value it must be... `export`ed. You can use either `module.exports = {url: 'localhost:3000'}` or `export const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com'` syntax depending on your project tools

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45764743/how-to-import-and-export-javascript-es6-classes

Comment: Might be a tad primitive, but you could also put the variable in the [global variable scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) w/o `export` -- `export` is the better practice route though. As written `newUrl` is only defined within the function scope of your event listener

Comment: But [btnFetch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(newUrl);});] is not a function :c ... ... I do not understand how it is done